# JDBC table/view does not exists

Tags: sql, database, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

I tried to create a simple project just to show me what was in my database.

So I created a new database in Netbeans's Services tab, created the table and fill them. Then I went to the `Glassfish` admin panel to create the `JDBC Connection Pool` and `Resource`.

Pool :

```
Pool Name :      BDDPool    
Resource Type :  javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
Classname :      org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource40
```

Resource :

```
JNDI Name :        jdbc/BDD
Connection Pool :  BDDPool
```

Back on NetBeans, I created a simple DAO file to retrieve data with a query :

```
package model.ejb;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 *
 * @author Choup
 */
@Stateless
public class BDDDAO {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/BDD")
    private DataSource ds;

    public void retrieveData(){
        try{
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENT");
            while( rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Name"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Address"));
            }
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I run it all and here's what I got :

> ```
> Infos:   Projet_Fitts was successfully deployed in 206 milliseconds.
> Grave:   La table/vue 'STUDENT' n'existe pas.
> ```
>
> => Table/view student does not exist.

So I search for a while and there might be a JDBC URL to put somewhere but I don't have that much files, only a `glassfish-web.xml`.

BTW: I can ping the database on the admin panel. If you have any suggestions or need more info let me know.

Comment: Is the Student table accessible by your login that you provided for your data source?

Comment: I don't understand what is my data source but I know that the table Student have no protection whatsoever in the database, I also know that the login password for that bdd is correct and works. And finally i did try this on a pre-working database given in an exemple and it did not work too so it must be a missing link between the code and the database someswhere but I don't know where

Comment: This error can happen because of two reasons(as far as i know) - 1) The table actually not being there. 2) Table not being accessible to the user. Second option seems likely and hence what I am asking is, the user credentials given to the datasource(jdbc/BDD) is having access to the student table right?

Comment: Yes the user can access the data, when created, I choose the user attribute for the JDBC Resource

Comment: In fact, since i'm really new at this I'm not even sure about the classname and resource type of the database